# Searching files by size range

Tags: bash, scripts, find

I have to find files by size. Sizes are parameters. Result of found files must be saved to file. I already got this:

```
touch result.txt 
find /var/log -type f -size $1 -size $2 -exec ls {} \; > result.txt
```

script shows me some results but I'm not sure they are right and nothing is saving to file.
Anybody can help?

Comment: Saving to file doesn't work with `-exec`. Use `-ls` instead. Also, a redirection will create a file if it doesn't exist yet, so the `touch` command is unnecessary.

Comment: The size parameter has a couple of quirks that are described in `man find`. E.g. sizes are rounded up to the next unit (bytes, blocks, kb, Mb). Therefore, finding `-1M` would match only empty files. You would only use two parameters if you wanted to find files "less than $1" and "more than $2". Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to find files which size i between these two parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use like :

```
find /var/log -type f -size -10M -size +1M -exec ls {} \; > result.txt
```

It will store files name that have size more than 1Mb and less than 10Mb.

```
cat result.txt
/var/log/wtmp
/var/log/audit/audit.log.1
/var/log/audit/audit.log
/var/log/anaconda/journal.log
/var/log/mongo/mongod-11.0.0.11.log
```

If you pass as input parameters then use like:

```
find /var/log -type f -size -"$1"M -size +"$2"M -exec ls {} \; > result.txt
```

Below are the available units for size.

```
  -size n[cwbkMG]
          File uses n units of space, rounding up.  The following
          suffixes can be used:

          `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix
                 is used)

          `c'    for bytes

          `w'    for two-byte words

          `k'    for Kibibytes (KiB, units of 1024 bytes)

          `M'    for Mebibytes (MiB, units of 1024 * 1024 = 1048576
                 bytes)

          `G'    for Gibibytes (GiB, units of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 =
                 1073741824 bytes)
```

Comment: `find` has an `ls` option, that should be much faster.

Comment: a simple tweak to look for any sizes: `findsize () { rem="param1: dir, param2:min, param3:max" ; find "$1" -type f -size -"$3" -size +"$2" -exec ls '{}' ';' > result.txt ;}` and use like:  `findsize /var/log 1M 10M` to find the same as your exemple.

Answer (score 2):

The files you find can be sorted numerically (using the size column) like this

```
find /var/log -ls |sort -nk7
```

You can store the result in a file if you wish

```
find /var/log -ls |sort -nk7 > result.txt
```